# Is Java's EOFException exceptional?

Tags: java, exception, io, inputstream, eofexception

It seems dirty to use an exception to indicate the end of a file has been reached. Every file we read has an end, so it doesn't seem exceptional or unexpected. Furthermore, I don't like using an exception for the non-exceptional flow of my program.

I'm talking about using [java.io.EOFException](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/EOFException.html) to signal the end of a data input stream:

Imagine a file consisting of the following messages...

```
----------------- ------------------
- 2-byte LENGTH - - N-byte PAYLOAD - , where N = LENGTH;
----------------- ------------------
```

...and reading this file with DataInputStream:

```
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(...);

...

try {
    while (true) {
        short length = in.readShort();
        byte[] b = new byte[length];
        in.readFully(b);
    }
} catch (EOFException e) { }

...
```

In this example, an EOFException is thrown by the call to `in.readShort()`. Should I figure out the number of bytes in the file, and read exactly that number of bytes (determined by `total -= length` going to zero), and exit the while-loop without an exception? I'm kind of looking for best practice.

Should I do something like this?

```
long total = file.length();
while (total > 0) {
    short length = in.readShort();
    total -= length;
    byte[] b = new byte[length];
    in.readFully(b);
}
```

The API Specification specifies that EOFException signals an end of file or end of stream has been reached *unexpectedly* during input. But it's also used by data input streams to signal end of stream.

What do I do when the excepted is expected?

Comment: That should be `total -= length+2`

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the [API specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readFully(byte[])) for the `DataInput.readFully` method:

```
 This method blocks until one of the following conditions occurs:

    * b.length bytes of input data are available, in which case a normal return is made.
    * End of file is detected, in which case an EOFException is thrown.
    * An I/O error occurs, in which case an IOException other than EOFException is thrown.
```

So the idea is that it's either going to read b.length bytes of data, or you get an error if it cannot do that, either because of I/O error or end of file is reached before b.length bytes can be read.

So you are expected to know how many bytes you want to read before calling `DataInput.readFully`. If you go past the end of the file, that is considered abnormal behavior, and hence, is the reason you get an exception.

Comment: In my example, the EOFException is thrown by `in.readShort();`. Should I do something else, like figure out the file's size and read exactly that number of bytes?

Comment: readShort works the same way. http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readShort%28%29 That is, you are expected know that a short is going to be available to read from the file, and if you try to read from the file and a short isn't there, you're going to get an exception. To avoid these types of issues, you could always use readAllBytes (http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/io/Inputs.html#readAllBytes%28java.nio.file.FileRef%29) You could also use readAllLines if you want the file data as strings.

Comment: Since I don't expect to readShort on the last call (when the file is completely read), what should I do?

Comment: If you are so opposed to using the exception, you could check the length of the file in advance, keep track of how many bytes you've read, and use that as the exit condition for your while loop. But of course you'd still need to catch the EOFException in case readFully() throws it (if the input file is somehow corrupted), so what would be the point?

Comment: Without knowing your file structure it's hard for me to say. Are you reading a fixed format file (i.e. field1 is 10 bytes, field2 is 20 bytes, field3 is 14 bytes, etc)? Are you reading a CSV file? It really depends on your input. If you are just reading a file full of numbers and you don't know how many there are, then it's going to be difficult to avoid the exception unless you read all the file text first and then work off of the strings.

Comment: @dcp file format is described in the question: records consisting of a 2-byte length followed by N bytes of data

Comment: @DAvid Gelhar - Yes, that wasn't there originally (I think), thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

You allude to the commonly given advice that exceptions should be used only for signalling exceptional events. The problem with this advice is that it replaces one uncertainty ("when to throw an exception') with another ("what is exceptional").

A different, and better answer, is that you should throw an exception if, and only if, the alternative would be failure to establish a post condition or to maintain an invariant.

The post condition of a read operation on an input stream is that a value has been successfully read. Clearly, no value can be read if we are at the EOF. So an exception of some type must be thrown. The calling code would want to halt reading, so it must be a distinctive type of exception (not a general IOException). Hence a specific EOFException is necessary.

The alternative is that read operations do not have successful reading as post conditions. This is what the C (POSIX) APIs do. In effect, each read operation is really a try-to-read operation. The reader code then needs to check a status code to see whether the attempt to read was actually successful. This style of code is difficult to understand, verbose, and error prone. one of the motivations for using exceptions rather than status codes is to avoid those difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

As its names suggests, `readFully` is used when you expect to read  fully some bunch of bytes, of known length. If EOF is reached before, that's unexpected, and then it's conceptually right to throw an exception. If you want the `read` semantic, then use the [read](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#read(byte[])) method.

Comment: Then what should I do in my example?